# Meteor cursor not returning correct number of data

Tags: meteor, minimongo

Just want to share my problem regarding the issue I've encountered just in case there's some geeks people who can help me. :-)

My problem is that... we are developing a meteor app using mongo as database and we have large number of data. Sometimes our query results gave us only few data or less than number of data of what we expect. We already used two methods of fetching the data:

```
Jobs_status_identifier.find(_where, _clr).fetch();
Jobs_status_identifier.find(_where, _clr).forEach(function(_d){});
```

...but still it only gave us 35 records where in facts we have 41 records for that statement in the database.

The mongo counter:

```
Jobs_status_identifier.find(_where, _clr).count();
```

it says... 41 but the .fetch and the .forEach only shows 35 records.

Does anyone here experienced the same or related problem?

Comment: What are _where and _clr. Show us some sample data and more code please. Thanks. I guess that you have limit in your projection variable _clr. The count gives you all records in collection and not care limits.

Comment: Are you running these queries on the client or server? i.e. is there a publish-subscribe involved?

Comment: @iiro, there's mo limit, if there's a limit based on the statement above they should display the same because they are running at the same time.

Comment: @MichelFloyd, it's running on the server side under method function.

Comment: @JuvyCagape ok, but "What are _where and _clr.". Show your code, please.

Comment: hi @iiro I explain it more here https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-app-mongodb-cursor-not-returning-correct-number-of-data/40548/7

Comment: check this out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36068573/mongodb-db-collection-count-vs-db-collection-find-length